# plot grid in background

Tags: matlab, background, grid

I use the [gridxy function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9973-gridxy-v2-2-feb-2008) (because the original grid can not be modified properly), which works very well.

But in this example the grid is painted in the foreground in the exported png:

```
figure(1); clf;
x = [0:0.1:10];
y = sin(x*pi/2).* x;
xtemp = [x(1) ; x(:) ; x(end)] ;
ytemp = [0 ; y(:) ; 0 ] ;
% plot
hplot = fill(xtemp,ytemp, 'b');
set(hplot, 'FaceColor' , [0.5, 0.5, 0.75])
set(hplot, 'EdgeColor' , [0, 0, 0.25])

hgrid = gridxy(get(gca,'XTick'),get(gca,'YTick'),'Color',[0.6 0.6 0.6],'Linestyle','--', 'LineWidth', 0.6);    

print(gcf, '-r400', ['test' '.png'], '-dpng');
```

As can be seen in this exported image:

[image]

Comment: `uistack(hgrid,'bottom')` should fix this (in fact, `gridxy` calls uistack), but it doesn't. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: FWIW, I submitted a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a complete explanation, but at least a working solution.

First of all, it seems that setting the figure's `RenderMode` property to `opengl` or `zbuffer` makes the image on screen look like the printed one (grid on top), and setting it to `painters` makes the grid go back to background. From the help of `print`:

> A note on renderers: when printing figures, MATLAB does not always use
>   the same renderer as on screen. This is for efficiency reasons. There
>   are cases, however, where the printed output is not exactly like the
>   screen representation because of this. In these instances specifying
>   -zbuffer or -opengl will more likely give you output that emulates the screen.

However, trying to use each of the available renderers, i.e `painters`,`zbuffer`, or `opengl`, gives somewhat different results, but all with the grid on top:

```
% Problem still exists in all 3 options:
print(gcf, '-r100', ['test1' '.png'], '-dpng','-painters');
print(gcf, '-r100', ['test1' '.png'], '-dpng','-zbuffer');
print(gcf, '-r100', ['test1' '.png'], '-dpng','-opengl');
```

Putting a breakpoint in line 142 in the file `toolbox\matlab\graphics\private\render.m`, and then calling `print` with `-painters` option, reveals that the 3rd input passed to `hardcopy` is `-dzbuffer`. If you change it to `-dpainters`:

```
inputargs{3}='-dpainters' % while in breakpoint
```

and then hit F5 to continue, the grid in the produced image goes to background.